# "heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput" returns "no module named haystack"

Tags: django, heroku, django-haystack

Locally, haystack is working fine when I open the project in my server.
Issues arise when I try to push to heroku. I get a collectstatic configuration error. When I try to debug using `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` I get this message `ImportError: No module named haystack`.

1. In my virtualenv, Django-haystack in installed
2. Locally, haystack works.
3. I have no items yet inside my staticfiles folder/directory.
4. Previously, I had a `Template does not exist` error. My virtualenv is named the same as my project so django only entered in 2 files instead of the 3. Could the error here be similar?

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

Comment: additionnally, when I run import haystack through the shell, no error messages are displayed.

Comment: Is haystack in your requirements.txt?

Comment: When you say import haystack works through the shell, is that on your server of remotely on heroku? I'm guessing Daniel's answer seems the most likely.

Comment: django haystack is listed in my requirements.txt  .  There is a rather interesting problem: Deploying on heroku now works, but I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error (my Debug is set to True)